# Efficiently inserting data into an SQL table with pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc, pymssql

Given a table with a several dozen columns what would be a proper way to insert data from a dataframe with something like:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dbo.table(column1,...column99) values(%s,...)",(row.column1,...row.column99)
```

without having to type dozens of %s, considering that it's inside a string?

Comment: If your data is in a DataFrame, ideally you'd use [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) and leave the abstraction to pandas' pre-existing implementation. Any reason you're hesitant to do this?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2016+ you can use [this method](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/1fb0f1c3f5edbf6192e596de8350f205) with pandas' `.to_sql()`.